# Vault ruby on rails giving ssl connection error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl, hashicorp-vault

I have one project we are using vautl I am using it for local development, Where `Rails s` working fine.

But when I want to run `rails c` console it give me following error

```
/Users/xyz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:44:in `connect_nonblock': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: wrong version number (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
    from /Users/xyz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:44:in `ssl_socket_connect'
    from /Users/xyz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:996:in `connect'
    from /Users/xyz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:930:in `do_start'
    from /Users/xyz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:925:in `start'
    from /Users/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@bb-rails/gems/vault-0.15.0/lib/vault/persistent.rb:698:in `start'
```

I have following class in `lib/utils/vault_config.rb

```
class VaultConfig
  def self.read(path)
    Vault.configure do |config|
      config.address = "http://127.0.0.1:8200"
      config.token = "my_tooken"
      config.ssl_verify = false
    end
    Vault.with_retries(Vault::HTTPConnectionError, Vault::HTTPError, attempts: 5) do
      secret = Vault.logical.read("secret/#{path}/#{Rails.env}")
      secret ||= Vault.logical.read("secret/#{path}")
      secret && OpenStruct.new(secret.data)
    end
  end
end
```

I am running vault development instance and it is in `http` not `https` and as it is for development only. So how can make sure `rails c` should not use ssl.

Comment: If you are using the Vault bindings as a singleton, then you need to add a block to configure Vault to now use SSL. The code needs to be restructured for Vault configuration.

Comment: Well I did try that as I updated above code with configure block but it did not work. Any idea how I can convert it to normal configuration or is something I am doing wrong in configure. As only field I can file is `verify_ssl`

Comment: That code executes without errors? Your block lambda scope variable is `config` and not `vault`.

Comment: Yes it does not generate any error but does not connect and after a while is shows SSL verification error for vault.

Comment: What happens when you fix the variable name?

Comment: Thank you very much sorry I have few errors their now it is working perfectly. Good help. Appreciate it.